# Oracle Forms 10g to 11g migration Error

Tags: oracle-10g, oracle-11g, migration

I having problems from first steps, while migrating Oracle Forms from 10g to 11g. Some of libraries dose not want to compile. the compiler just hangs up when I try to compile them, and Forms builder hangs up when I try to open them. Error signature

```
AppName: frmcmp.exe  AppVer: 11.1.2.1    ModName: orapls11.dll
ModVer: 11.1.0.7     Offset: 00002541
```

I checked libraries relations, everything looks fine. Does anybody had similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Oracle bug. When sometimes opening librarys in Oracle Builder 11g which is compiled with Oracle Builder 10g The 11g Builder crashes. I solved this problem by converting librarys to pld in Oracle Builder 10g and then converting them back to pll with Oracle Builder 11g.